# EasyAdmin - how to create admin account

Tags: php, symfony, psql, easyadmin

my problem is simple. I'm trying to create admin account with authentication by this simple way:

```
$ symfony composer req security
$ symfony console make:user Admin
```

I'm doing whole configuration in the files from the tutorial (https://symfony.com/doc/current/the-fast-track/pl/15-security.html) and:

```
$ symfony console security:encode-password
$ symfony run psql -c "INSERT INTO admin (id, username, roles, password) \
  VALUES (nextval('admin_id_seq'), 'admin', '[\"ROLE_ADMIN\"]', \ '\$2y$13$WbjbWP7f3KrRbO0XKkECmuOMInik.xPS5bWgE72dgslRFmMLMBuRq')"
```

The command `symfony run psql -c` doesn't work properly on my Windows10, so I created same thing in the terminal by psql `psql -h localhost -U postgres`:

```
INSERT INTO admin (id, username, roles, password)
VALUES ('1', 'admin', '["ROLE_ADMIN"]', '$2y$13$ELXmuFKvzmE4x9crO58LmOp4CEle1578nEGhriJcZJLemKgB9qlsO');
```

New fields have been created in the database, but I still cannot login in to the easyAdmin panel, and I haven't idea what I am doing wrong.

[image]

Security.yaml

```
security:
    enable_authenticator_manager: true
    password_hashers:
        App\Entity\Admin:
            algorithm: auto

providers:
        app_user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\Admin
                property: username
firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            lazy: true
            provider: app_user_provider
            custom_authenticator: App\Security\AppAuthenticator
            logout:
                path: app_logout

         - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
#         - { path: ^/profile, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

AppAuthenticator

```
public function authenticate(Request $request): PassportInterface
{
    $username = $request->request->get('username', '');

    $request->getSession()->set(Security::LAST_USERNAME, $username);

    return new Passport(
        new UserBadge($username),
        new PasswordCredentials($request->request->get('password', '')),
        [
            new CsrfTokenBadge('authenticate', $request->get('_csrf_token')),
        ]
    );
}

public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, string $firewallName): ?Response
{
    if ($targetPath = $this->getTargetPath($request->getSession(), $firewallName)) {
        return new RedirectResponse($targetPath);
    }

    return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('admin'));
}
```